# Ошибка 403 в Git

Tags: git, github, mingw

Скачал проект с GitHub, все файлы добавил, написал коммит - все хорошо. Когда пишу `git push -u origin alexandr_front-end` показывает `Error: 403`[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Убедитесь, что правильно задано имя пользователя и пароль.

Comment: Так репозиторий, судя по названию, не ваш. Почему вы решили, что можете так запросто добавлять изменения в чужой репозиторий? Почитайте справку гитхаба.

Answer (score 4):

Всё логично, если это не ваш репозиторий, то напрямую вы не можете вносить изменения. Это так не работает. Воркфлоу должен быть такой. Сначала, средствами гитхаба, форкаете репозиторий в свой аккаунт на гитхабе, потом клонируете форк к себе в локальный репозиторий, вносите изменения, стейджите, коммитите и заливаете изменения на гитхаб. После этого можно делать пулл реквест в оригинальный репозиторий.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка 403 (Forbidden) обозначает, что пользователь не имеет доступа к файлам. Может быть вы имеете дело с приватным репозиторием, а вы неправильно ввели свой логин и/или пароль.